# Add category section and save in database in admin section with java and javafx using mvc

Tags: java, mvc, javafx

As I newbie in (java and MVC), I want to know if I understand MVC using java.

My concern is that some of the calls of the class are in the wrong place or, for example, I should have used the interface (of course, I don't know the advantage of using the interface assigned to the class in this case).
I also want to know what are the shortcomings of these classes.

I apologize for my simple questions, but as a newbie, I need expert opinions.

My view is:

```
public CategoryPage() throws SQLException {
        Label lblTitle = new Label("Title: ");
        title = new TextField();

        HBox row1 = new HBox(lblTitle, title);
        row1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label lblCatList = new Label("Categories: ");
        categoryList = new ComboBox<>();

        HBox row2 = new HBox(lblCatList, categoryList);
        row1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        btnSave = new Button("Save");
        btnSave.setOnAction(e -> {
            category.setName(title.getText());
            try {
                category.setParentId
                        (category.getParentId
                                (categoryList.getValue().toString()));
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            try {
                int id = categoryDao.saveCategory(category);
                category.setId(id);
                CategoryController categoryController = new CategoryController();
                categoryController.initCategoryList(categoryList);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }

        });

        this.getChildren().addAll(row1, row2, btnSave);
        this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        this.setSpacing(16);
    }
}
```

I have `Category` and `CategryDao` in model and `CategoryController` in controller.

My Controller is:

```
public class CategoryController {
    private CategoryPage categoryPage;
    private CategoryDao categoryDao = new CategoryDao();
    private ComboBox catList;
    public CategoryController () throws SQLException {
        categoryPage = new CategoryPage();
        catList = categoryPage.getCategoryList();
        initCategoryList(catList);
    }

    public CategoryPage getPage() {
        return categoryPage;
    }

    public void initCategoryList(ComboBox catList) {
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            items = categoryDao.getAllCategories();
            ObservableList<String> comboItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(items);
            catList.setItems(comboItems);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and Model:

```
public class Category {
    private String name;
    private int id = -1;
    private int parentId = 0;
    private CategoryDao categoryDao = new CategoryDao();


    public void setParentId(int parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Category() {
        DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection();
    }
    public int getParentId(String name) throws SQLException {
        int id = categoryDao.selectedCategoryItem(name);
        this.setParentId(id);
        return parentId;
    }
    public int getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }
}
```

**Update:** This section was changed based on the statements of `Joop Eggen`. (I want to write a class to log the errors)

```
//-------------------------------------------
public class CategoryDao {
    DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection();

    public CategoryDao() {
    }

   public List<String> getAllCategories() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = dbConnection.makeConnection();
        ResultSet rs;
        PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
        try {
            pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("Select * From categories");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try {
            rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
            List<String> catList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                catList.add(rs.getString("name"));
            }
            rs.close();
            connection.close();
            return catList;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public int saveCategory(Category category) {
        String name = category.getName();
        int parentId = category.getParentId();
        Connection connection = dbConnection.makeConnection();
        PreparedStatement pStmt;
        String query = "Insert Into categories(name,parent_id) values (?, ?)";
        try {
            pStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try {
            pStmt.setString(1, name);
            pStmt.setInt(2, parentId);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        try {
            pStmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            rs = pStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try {
            if(rs.next()) {
                int last_inserted_id = rs.getInt(1);
                if (last_inserted_id != -1) {
                    try {
                        dbConnection.closeConnection();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    return last_inserted_id;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try {
            dbConnection.closeConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

The program worked and save the category in database.

Answer (score 3):

The architecture could indeed be a bit more like Model-View-Controller, but I would first concentrate on the more clear code usage.

It must be said that some knowledge is demonstrated here. Like generated DB keys.

#### The layout

It is helpful to also install the SceneBuilder, a GUI application for creating forms. The generated code might give insight in details.

A `GridPane` is for forms a more comfortable layout.

`Label` may point to the edit control. This allows to click on the label and let the controller get focus, or other hightlight to label when the edit control has the focus. (Theme dependent.) In HTML that would be `<label for="MyEditField">`,

```
TextField textField = ...
Label label = ...
label.setLabelFor(textField);
```

#### Java - Use interfaces

Programming against interfaces (here interface `List` instead of class `ArrayList`). Your code will become more versatile, as the implementing class may easily be interchanged later. And a *parameter* `List<...>` can handle more than just an `ArrayList`. And a *result* `List<...>` may be dynamically implemented for 0 elements with `Collections.emptyList`, for 1 with `Collections.singletonList`.

> Some programming languages do not provide the notion of interface with several implementing classes. There is just one specific container class, say for List. Having separate varying implementations is beneficial.

```
// *** ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### JDBC and try-with-resources

Try-with-resources is where you have variables declared inside `try (...)` of Closable's and whatever happens, return, throw exception, the object will be closed.

```
public List<String> getAllCategories() throws SQLException {
    try (Connection connection = dbConnection.makeConnection();
            PreparedStatement pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM categories") {
        // pStmt.setString(1, ...):
        try (ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery()) {
            List<String> catList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                catList.add(rs.getString("name"));
            }
            return catList;
        } // Always close rs.
    } // Always close pStmt and dbConnection
}
```

Stylistic I am not sure, but I would refrain for SQL keywords from camelcase `Select` in favor of either `select` or `SELECT`.

#### Exception handling

When having a `throws` of an exception, catching one, or rethrowing a checked exception as a runtime exception? Your code looks mature enough, though you have spared yourself a bit.

However please do not rethrow the "base" class `RuntimeException`. When catching it somewhere the stacktrace might be too long to see the cause. And a RuntimeException does not give any meaning. IllegalArgumentException means data is fishy, IllegalStateException, the programmer is guilty.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // *** throw new RuntimeException(e);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

#### ComboBox

You simplified the usage of ComboBox to String. You could experiment with a `ComboBox<Category>` or such.

#### System.out.println versus Logging

Logging is better as it may be configured to not show up in the production usage. Or have only errors in a separate time stamped log file.

There are several logging frameworks in java. `java…util.logging` is the basic standard logging. However there is something every java developer should know.
`System.Logger` is a logging facade, which has been implemented by most logging frameworks. This allows you to create a library using `System.Logger` and any using third party application may use their own logging framework. Of course you may use System.Logger everywhere. The standard available java.util.Logging will be used, if nothing is configured.

#### Model-View-Controller

You collect some GUI fields (View) of data (Model) and then "save" them (Controller). Such things can happen in different classes. The controller is central. This need not be the JavaFX scene Controller.

This is the *architecture* you were requesting feedback on. Unfortunately one has to split code as said above.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I changed database function and try to solve the problems. In the **Model-View-Controller** section, I didn't understand what to do. If there is a problem with the code, please let me know.(I update the db section)

Comment: I read about interfaces but don't know in this project is usfull or not?! for example can I use interfaces for database queries?

Comment: In general interfaces are more used for the container classes: List, Set, Map. Where the implementation may vary. Near to an interface is a base class where child classes are specific implementation. So no need to introduce an interface or base class when it does not simplify (removing code copies).

Comment: I was not exactly detailed on MVC. Best are examples of MVC in small applications. It is a matter of isolating the three aspects.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to touch on the `MVC` pattern in `JavaFX`. Your code does use `JavaFX's` MVC architect, but it appears to lack an `MVC` pattern. The way I see the `MVC` pattern is everything goes through the `DataModel`.

The `DataModel` should keep up with states and data that more than one `Scene` may need. The `DataModel` should also handle DB operations in my opinion. Some may disagree with this. I have used many apps where the database is open until the app is closed. In the case I am presenting, the `DataModel` Opens the DB, runs a query on the DB, and then closes the DB. The `DataModel` should then be shared with all `Scenes`/`Controllers` that will need the current state or some data.

Example:

### App

Load the DataModel when the app loads. This is a good time to load any data. You can use a splash screen if there are lots of things that need to be done. This creates the `DataModel` and sets the `HostServices` so that the `HostServices` are available to each `Controller`. The `DataModel` is then set to the first `Scene`/`Controller`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import sed.work.databasebytitleandsubject.model.DataModel;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
        dataModel.setHostServices(getHostServices());
        FXMLLoader primaryLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("primary.fxml"));
        Parent parent = primaryLoader.load();
        PrimaryController primaryController = primaryLoader.getController();
        primaryController.initModel(dataModel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

### DataModel

Here is how DataModel Looks. It holds Observerable states, holds data, and handles DB calls.

```
import sed.work.databasebytitleandsubject.dao.ByTitleDatabaseHandler;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.HostServices;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import sed.work.databasebytitleandsubject.dao.BySubjectDatabaseHandler;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class DataModel {
    private HostServices hostServices;
    
    public void setHostServices(HostServices hostServices)
    {
        this.hostServices = hostServices;
    }
    
    public HostServices getHostServices()
    {
        return this.hostServices;
    }
    
    private final ObservableList<DatabaseByTitle> databaseByTitleObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();  
   
    public ObservableList<DatabaseByTitle> getDatabaseByTitleObservableList()
    {
        return this.databaseByTitleObservableList;
    }
    
    private final ObjectProperty<DatabaseByTitle> currentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItem = new SimpleObjectProperty();
    
    public void setCurrentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItem(DatabaseByTitle databaseByTitle)
    {
        currentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItem.set(databaseByTitle);
    }
    
    public DatabaseByTitle getCurrentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItem()
    {
        return this.currentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItem.get();
    }
    
    public ObjectProperty<DatabaseByTitle> currentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItemProperty()
    {
        return this.currentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItem;
    }
    
   
    
    
    
    
    
    public List<DatabaseByTitle> getAllDatabaseByTitleEntries()
    {
        List<DatabaseByTitle> output = new ArrayList();
        
        try (ByTitleDatabaseHandler byTitleDatabaseHandler = new ByTitleDatabaseHandler()) 
        {
            output = byTitleDatabaseHandler.getAllEntries();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DataModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return output;
    }
    
    public boolean deleteDatabaseByTitleEntry(DatabaseByTitle databaseByTitle)
    {
        try (ByTitleDatabaseHandler byTitleDatabaseHandler = new ByTitleDatabaseHandler()) 
        {
            return byTitleDatabaseHandler.deleteEntry(databaseByTitle);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DataModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean addNewDatabaseByTitleEntry(DatabaseByTitle databaseByTitle)
    {
        try (ByTitleDatabaseHandler byTitleDatabaseHandler = new ByTitleDatabaseHandler()) 
        {
            return byTitleDatabaseHandler.addNewEntry(databaseByTitle);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DataModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean updateDatabaseByTitleEntry(DatabaseByTitle databaseByTitle)
    {
        try (ByTitleDatabaseHandler byTitleDatabaseHandler = new ByTitleDatabaseHandler()) 
        {
            return byTitleDatabaseHandler.updateEntry(databaseByTitle);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DataModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public int getLastTableId(String tableName)
    {
        try (ByTitleDatabaseHandler byTitleDatabaseHandler = new ByTitleDatabaseHandler()) 
        {
            return byTitleDatabaseHandler.getLastIDFromTable(tableName);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DataModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    public List<DatabaseBySubject> getAllEntryiesBySubject(Subject subject)
    {
        List<DatabaseBySubject> output = new ArrayList();
        
        try (BySubjectDatabaseHandler bySubjectDatabaseHandler = new BySubjectDatabaseHandler()) 
        {
            output = bySubjectDatabaseHandler.getAllEntryiesBySubject(subject);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DataModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return output;
    }
    
    public List<Subject> getAllSubjects()
    {
        List<Subject> output = new ArrayList();
        
        try (BySubjectDatabaseHandler bySubjectDatabaseHandler = new BySubjectDatabaseHandler()) 
        {
            output = bySubjectDatabaseHandler.getAllSubjects();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DataModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return output;
    }
    
    public boolean deleteInsertSubjectItems(List<DatabaseBySubject> databaseBySubjectList, Subject subject)
    {
        BySubjectDatabaseHandler bySubjectDatabaseHandler = new BySubjectDatabaseHandler();
        if(bySubjectDatabaseHandler.deleteMainSubject(subject.getId()))
        {
            if(bySubjectDatabaseHandler.insertMainSubject(databaseBySubjectList, subject))
            {
                bySubjectDatabaseHandler.closeConnection();
                
                return true;
            }
        }
            
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

### Primary Controller

Here is an example of the `DataModel` being used throughout a `Controller`. Look at the method `handleBtnSwtichByTitleOnAction`, to see how to pass the `DataModel` to another `Controller`. Look at the method `initModel` to see how the `DataModel` is initialized in each `Controller`.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sed.work.createdatabasebytitleandsubjectdatabase.DatabaseByTitleData;
import sed.work.createdatabasebytitleandsubjectdatabase.DatabaseHandler;
import sed.work.databasebytitleandsubject.model.DataModel;
import sed.work.databasebytitleandsubject.model.DatabaseByTitle;


public class PrimaryController implements Initializable{
    @FXML TableView<DatabaseByTitle> tvDatabaseByTitle;
    @FXML private TableColumn<DatabaseByTitle, Number> tcId;
    @FXML TableColumn<DatabaseByTitle, String> tcName, tcAbout, tcNumberOfUsers, tcLink, tcAccess;
    @FXML Button btnEditByTitleEntry, btnDeleteByTitleEntry;
    @FXML TextField tfByTitleEntry;
    @FXML ChoiceBox<String> cbByTitleEntry;
    
    DataModel dataModel;
    FilteredList<DatabaseByTitle> filteredList;
    
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        tcId.setCellValueFactory((param) -> param.getValue().idProperty());
        tcName.setCellValueFactory((param) -> param.getValue().nameProperty());
        tcAbout.setCellValueFactory((param) -> param.getValue().aboutProperty());
        tcNumberOfUsers.setCellValueFactory((param) -> param.getValue().numberOfUsersProperty());
        tcLink.setCellValueFactory((param) -> param.getValue().linkProperty());
        tcAccess.setCellValueFactory((param) -> param.getValue().accessProperty());   
        
        tcAbout.setCellFactory((TableColumn<DatabaseByTitle, String> param) -> {
            TableCell<DatabaseByTitle, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
            Text text = new Text();
            cell.setGraphic(text);
            cell.setPrefHeight(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(cell.widthProperty());
            text.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());
            
            return cell ;
        });       
        
        tvDatabaseByTitle.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue != null)
            {
                dataModel.setCurrentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItem(newValue);
            }
        });
        
        btnDeleteByTitleEntry.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(tvDatabaseByTitle.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
        btnEditByTitleEntry.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(tvDatabaseByTitle.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
        
        cbByTitleEntry.setOnAction((event) -> {
            tfByTitleEntry.setText("");
        });
                
                
        tfByTitleEntry.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue != null)
            {
                if(newValue.isEmpty())
                {
                    filteredList.setPredicate(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    Predicate<DatabaseByTitle> namePredicate = (t) -> t.getName().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase());
                    Predicate<DatabaseByTitle> aboutPredicate = (t) -> t.getAbout().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase());
                    Predicate<DatabaseByTitle> numOfUsersPredicate = (t) -> t.getNumberOfUsers().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase());
                    Predicate<DatabaseByTitle> linkPredicate = (t) -> t.getLink().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase());
                    Predicate<DatabaseByTitle> accessPredicate = (t) -> t.getAccess().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase());
                    switch(cbByTitleEntry.getValue())
                    {
                        case "All" -> filteredList.setPredicate(namePredicate.or(aboutPredicate).or(numOfUsersPredicate).or(linkPredicate).or(accessPredicate));
                        case "Name" -> filteredList.setPredicate(namePredicate);
                        case "About" -> filteredList.setPredicate(aboutPredicate);
                        case "Number Of Users" -> filteredList.setPredicate(numOfUsersPredicate);
                        case "Link" -> filteredList.setPredicate(linkPredicate);
                        case "Access" -> filteredList.setPredicate(accessPredicate);
                    } 
                }
            }
        });
    }
       
    @FXML
    public void handleBtnAddByTitleEntryOnAction(){
        // Create the custom dialog.
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Dialog<DatabaseByTitle> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Database By Title");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Add New Entry");

        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType btntAdd = new ButtonType("Add", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        ButtonType btntCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(btntAdd, btntCancel);

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

        TextField tfName = new TextField();
        TextArea taAbout = new TextArea();
        taAbout.setWrapText(true);
        TextField tfNumberOfUsers = new TextField();
        TextField tfLink = new TextField();
        TextField tfAccess = new TextField();

        grid.add(new Label("Name: "), 0, 1);
        grid.add(tfName, 1, 1, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("About: "), 0, 2);
        grid.add(taAbout, 1, 2, 3, 4);
        grid.add(new Label("Number of Users: "), 0, 7);
        grid.add(tfNumberOfUsers, 1, 7, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("Link: "), 0, 8);
        grid.add(tfLink, 1, 8, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("Access: "), 0, 9);
        grid.add(tfAccess, 1, 9, 3, 1);

        Button btnAdd = (Button)dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(btntAdd);        
        btnAdd.disableProperty().bind(
            Bindings.isEmpty(tfName.textProperty())
            .or(Bindings.isEmpty(taAbout.textProperty()))
            .or(Bindings.isEmpty(tfNumberOfUsers.textProperty()))
            .or(Bindings.isEmpty(tfLink.textProperty()))
            .or(Bindings.isEmpty(tfAccess.textProperty()))
        );

        root.setCenter(grid);       
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(root);
        
        dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == btntAdd) {              
                return new DatabaseByTitle(-1L, tfName.getText(), taAbout.getText(), tfNumberOfUsers.getText(), tfLink.getText(), tfAccess.getText());
            }
            return null;
        });
        Optional<DatabaseByTitle> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        result.ifPresent((databaseByTitleEntry) -> {
            if(dataModel.addNewDatabaseByTitleEntry(databaseByTitleEntry)){
                int newParcelId = dataModel.getLastTableId("main");
                if(newParcelId > 0){
                    databaseByTitleEntry.setId(newParcelId);
                    dataModel.getDatabaseByTitleObservableList().add(databaseByTitleEntry);
                }
                else{
                    //Todo - add error alert!
                }
            }
        });    
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void handleBtnDeleteByTitleEntryOnAction(){
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Database By Title");
        alert.setHeaderText("Delete Entry");
        
        DatabaseByTitle currentlySelectedEntry = dataModel.getCurrentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItem();
        alert.setContentText("Are you sure you want to delete " + currentlySelectedEntry.getName() + "?");

        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK)
        {
            if(dataModel.deleteDatabaseByTitleEntry(currentlySelectedEntry))
            {
                dataModel.getDatabaseByTitleObservableList().remove(currentlySelectedEntry);
            }
            else
            {
                //Todo - Show alert said it failed!
            }
        }
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void handleBtnAboutByTitleOnAction(){
        //Todo
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void handleBtnJsonByTitleOnAction()
    {
        DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String date = LocalDateTime.now().format(myFormatObj).replace(":", "_").replace(" ", "T");
                
        try (DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler()) {
            List<DatabaseByTitleData> databaseByTitleDatas = databaseHandler.getByTitleItemsSorted();
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting();
            Gson gson = builder.create();
            String gsonOutput = gson.toJson(databaseByTitleDatas);
            Files.write(Paths.get("databases_by_title_" + date + ".json"), gsonOutput.getBytes());
            File file = new File("databases_by_title_" + date + ".json");
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                alert.setTitle("By Title Dialog");
                alert.setHeaderText("File Created Dialog");
                alert.setContentText("Would you like to open this file?");
                TextArea textArea = new TextArea(file.getAbsolutePath());
                textArea.setWrapText(true);
                textArea.setEditable(false);
                alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(textArea);
                Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
                if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
                    dataModel.getHostServices().showDocument(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void handleBtnEditByTitleEntryOnAction(){
        DatabaseByTitle currentlySelectedItem = dataModel.getCurrentSelectedDatabaseByTitleItem();
        
        // Create the custom dialog.
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Dialog<DatabaseByTitle> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Database By Title");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Edit Entry");

        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType btntAdd = new ButtonType("Done", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        ButtonType btntCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(btntAdd, btntCancel);

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

        TextField tfName = new TextField(currentlySelectedItem.getName());
        TextArea taAbout = new TextArea(currentlySelectedItem.getAbout());
        taAbout.setWrapText(true);
        TextField tfNumberOfUsers = new TextField(currentlySelectedItem.getNumberOfUsers());
        TextField tfLink = new TextField(currentlySelectedItem.getLink());
        TextField tfAccess = new TextField(currentlySelectedItem.getAccess());

        grid.add(new Label("Name: "), 0, 1);
        grid.add(tfName, 1, 1, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("About: "), 0, 2);
        grid.add(taAbout, 1, 2, 3, 4);
        grid.add(new Label("Number of Users: "), 0, 7);
        grid.add(tfNumberOfUsers, 1, 7, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("Link: "), 0, 8);
        grid.add(tfLink, 1, 8, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("Access: "), 0, 9);
        grid.add(tfAccess, 1, 9, 3, 1);

        Button btnAdd = (Button)dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(btntAdd);        
        btnAdd.disableProperty().bind(
            Bindings.isEmpty(tfName.textProperty())
            .or(Bindings.isEmpty(taAbout.textProperty()))
            .or(Bindings.isEmpty(tfNumberOfUsers.textProperty()))
            .or(Bindings.isEmpty(tfLink.textProperty()))
            .or(Bindings.isEmpty(tfAccess.textProperty()))
        );

        root.setCenter(grid);       
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(root);
        
        dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == btntAdd) {              
                return new DatabaseByTitle(currentlySelectedItem.getId(), tfName.getText(), taAbout.getText(), tfNumberOfUsers.getText(), tfLink.getText(), tfAccess.getText());
            }
            return null;
        });
        Optional<DatabaseByTitle> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        result.ifPresent((databaseByTitleEntry) -> {
            if(dataModel.updateDatabaseByTitleEntry(databaseByTitleEntry))
            {
                currentlySelectedItem.setName(databaseByTitleEntry.getName());
                currentlySelectedItem.setAbout(databaseByTitleEntry.getAbout());
                currentlySelectedItem.setNumberOfUsers(databaseByTitleEntry.getNumberOfUsers());
                currentlySelectedItem.setLink(databaseByTitleEntry.getLink());
                currentlySelectedItem.setAccess(databaseByTitleEntry.getAccess());
            }
            else
            {
                //Todo - add error alert!
            }            
        });    
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void handleBtnSwtichByTitleOnAction(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        try 
        {
            Stage stage = (Stage)((Button) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            
            FXMLLoader secondaryLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("secondary.fxml"));
            Parent parent = secondaryLoader.load();
            SecondaryController secondaryController = secondaryLoader.getController();
            secondaryController.initModel(dataModel);
            
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            stage.setScene(scene);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(PrimaryController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
    
    
    
    
    
    
    public void initModel(DataModel dataModel) {
        // ensure dataModel is only set once:
        if (this.dataModel != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
        }

        this.dataModel = dataModel ;
        filteredList = new FilteredList(dataModel.getDatabaseByTitleObservableList());
        tvDatabaseByTitle.setItems(filteredList);
        dataModel.getDatabaseByTitleObservableList().addAll(dataModel.getAllDatabaseByTitleEntries());        
    }    
}
```

### Project Structure

You will notice that module-info is missing, and Main.java is added. You can ignore this. It's used as a workaround to avoid having to use `Java Modules`.

[image]

For more information on `MVC` in `JavaFX`, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx).